# Email and social sharing functionality

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, email

I have an web app where users can create their own stores. To help them promote their stores I'd like to add the ability for them to type in their email, and share their store listing with their email contacts whether it's gmail, outlook, yahoo, hotmail etc... similar to how Linkedin does this. Basically once they enter their email, a list of "suggested friends" (from their email contacts) will pop-up that they can select and share with.

Are there any reactJS or rails gems for this? Looking for a head start so I don't have to code it all from scratch.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Looking for a gem for this too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can look into [OmniContacts](https://github.com/Diego81/omnicontacts)

> Inspired by the popular OmniAuth, OmniContacts is a library that
>   enables users of an application to import contacts from their email or
>   Facebook accounts. The email providers currently supported are Gmail,
>   Yahoo and Hotmail. OmniContacts is a Rack middleware, therefore you
>   can use it with Rails, Sinatra and any other Rack-based framework.

Usage:

1) Add to your Gemfile
`gem "omnicontacts"`

2) Create initializer

```
#config/initializers/omnicontacts.rb
require "omnicontacts"

Rails.application.middleware.use OmniContacts::Builder do
  importer :gmail, "client_id", "client_secret", {:redirect_path => "/oauth2callback", :ssl_ca_file => "/etc/ssl/certs/curl-ca-bundle.crt"}
  importer :yahoo, "consumer_id", "consumer_secret", {:callback_path => "/callback"}
  importer :linkedin, "consumer_id", "consumer_secret", {:redirect_path => "/oauth2callback", :state => '<long_unique_string_value>'}
  importer :hotmail, "client_id", "client_secret"
  importer :outlook, "app_id", "app_secret"
  importer :facebook, "client_id", "client_secret"
end
```

you can get more info from https://github.com/Diego81/omnicontacts

I hope that this can get you started